# How to increase the time before Jest exits after running tests

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer, e2e-testing, end-to-end

I'm writing a bunch of end-to-end tests for my NextJS app and all tests are passing. However, I'm having issues where my `afterAll` hook gives me `Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.`

This is my file structure:

```
src/
  tests/
    end-to-end/
      - T0001.login.test.tsx
      - T0002.nodes.test.tsx
      - T0003.users.test.tsx
```

I run my tests with the following script defined on my `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test:e2e": "jest ./src/tests/end-to-end/*.test.tsx --coverage --runInBand --verbose"
  }
}
```

After running `yarn test:e2e`, I get the following output:

```bash
 FAIL  src/tests/end-to-end/T0003.users.test.tsx (32.743 s)

  ● Test suite failed to run

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 20000 ms for a hook.
    Add a timeout value to this test to increase the timeout, if this is a long-running test. See https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout."

      203 |     });
      204 |
    > 205 |     afterAll(async () => {
          |     ^
      206 |             // Click the button to show the logout menu item
      207 |             await page.waitForSelector('#btn-header-user');
      208 |             await page.click('#btn-header-user');

      at afterAll (src/tests/end-to-end/T0003.users.test.tsx:205:2)
      at Object.describe (src/tests/end-to-end/T0003.users.test.tsx:5:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
Tests:       22 passed, 22 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        61.993 s

Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

I'm not sure what the problem is because on my first test suite (`T0001.login.test.tsx`):

```js
import puppeteer, { Browser, Page } from 'puppeteer';

describe('AUTHENTICATION', () => {
  let browser: Browser;
  let page: Page;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: 'new', args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });
    page = await browser.newPage();
  });

  // Begin Tests
  test();
  test();
  test();
  // End Tests

  afterAll(async () => {
    await browser.close();
  }, Constants.TEST_TIMEOUT);
});
```

On my second (`T0002.nodes.test.tsx`) and third (`T0003.users.test.tsx`) test suites, the set up is a bit different because I'll try to login from inside the `beforeAll` and logout from inside the `afterAll` hooks.

### Node Management

```js
import puppeteer, { Browser, Page } from 'puppeteer';

describe('NODE MANAGEMENT', () => {
  let browser: Browser;
  let page: Page;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: 'new', args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });
    page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('http://localhost:3000');

    // Enter the username
    await page.waitForSelector('#username');
    await page.focus('#username');
    await page.keyboard.type('user01');

    // Enter the password
    await page.waitForSelector('#password');
    await page.focus('#password');
    await page.keyboard.type('MyTotallySecurePassword');

    // Click the button to login
    await page.waitForSelector('#btn-login');
    await page.click('#btn-login');
  });

  // Begin Tests
  test();
  test();
  test();
  // End Tests

  afterAll(async () => {
    // Click the button to show the logout menu item
    await page.waitForSelector('#btn-header-user');
    await page.click('#btn-header-user');

    // Click the logout menu item
    await page.waitForSelector('#menu-item-logout');
    await page.click('#menu-item-logout');

    await browser.close();
  }, Constants.TEST_TIMEOUT);
});
```

### User Management

This uses the same exact `beforeAll` and `afterAll` setups as the other one which doesn't seem to give any kind of issues.

```js
import puppeteer, { Browser, Page } from 'puppeteer';

describe('USER MANAGEMENT', () => {
  let browser: Browser;
  let page: Page;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: 'new', args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });
    page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('http://localhost:3000');

    // Enter the username
    await page.waitForSelector('#username');
    await page.focus('#username');
    await page.keyboard.type('user01');

    // Enter the password
    await page.waitForSelector('#password');
    await page.focus('#password');
    await page.keyboard.type('MyTotallySecurePassword');

    // Click the button to login
    await page.waitForSelector('#btn-login');
    await page.click('#btn-login');
  });

  // Begin Tests
  test();
  test();
  test();
  // End Tests

  afterAll(async () => {
    // Click the button to show the logout menu item
    await page.waitForSelector('#btn-header-user');
    await page.click('#btn-header-user');

    // Click the logout menu item
    await page.waitForSelector('#menu-item-logout');
    await page.click('#menu-item-logout');

    await browser.close();
  }, Constants.TEST_TIMEOUT);
});
```

My understanding here is that Jest will try to exit 1000ms after the tests finish but that doesn't include the `afterAll` hook for cleaning up. I'm thinking the `afterAll` hook that includes logging out is taking more than the 1000ms time frame:

```bash
 PASS  src/tests/end-to-end/T0001.login.test.tsx (9.24 s)
  AUTHENTICATION
    ✓ contains the login form (3730 ms)
    ✓ displays the server version information (1038 ms)
    ✓ shows an error message when the user provides invalid credentials (1424 ms)
    ✓ logs the user in (1125 ms)
    ✓ logs the user out and shows the login page again (1316 ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to increase jest timeout in config?

Example for yarn executor in package.json

```
    "test": "jest -i --testTimeout=30000 --detectOpenHandles",
```

also you can try to run `jest.useRealTimers();` 
on the top level of your test, hopefully it would help.